$model->save() saving but with different value
When updating my cart model, I run:
$cart->transaction_id= $result->salePaymentRequestResult->token;
$cart->save();

This does update my cart. But it with different value. Why is my model not being updated correctly?
I get no errors.
The cart does not get updated in the db correctly.
No errors. Behavior as normal.
Result of running this test to see if save succeeded was true.
This Laravel thread was no help
cart model:

This seems to be an issue with the $result->salePaymentRequestResult->token value. Make sure you're retrieving the correct value. You can use dd() or return to verify.

Since your question is lacking context, I'll suggest isolating the statements and log the values. You can start by asking the following questions:

What's the value of $result->salePaymentRequestResult->token at that point of code?
What happens when you assign a static string to $cart->transaction_id? For example: $cart->transaction_id = 'test_token';
Is there any mutator defined for transaction_id attribute? Defining a Mutator
Is there any observer defined for the model? Observers


It’s possible that the issue is due to the $fillable attribute not including transaction_id. Laravel prevents mass assignment for fields that aren't in the $fillable array, which could cause the value not to save properly.
protected $fillable = ['transaction_id', /* other fields */];

Sometimes cached data might show old values.
php artisan cache:clear


fillable doesn't come into play when directly assigning an attribute
